# how can I make balls resize automatically using .arc

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a ball made by .arc function grow with time, and i want to be able to specify the duration. this is where I'm stuck:

```js
      function start(){
        var ball1,ball2,ball3,ball4;
        var ball=document.getElementById("MyCanvas");
        ball1=ball.getContext("2d");
        ball1.fillStyle="yellow";
        ball1.beginPath();
        ball1.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
        ball1.fill();
        scaling(ball1);
      }
      function scaling(ball){
        ball.beginPath();
        ball.arc(95,50,100,0,2*Math.PI);
      }
      window.addEventListener("load",start,false);
```

```css
body{background-color:white;}
```

```html
 <canvas id="MyCanvas" width="1000" height="500" style="border:black 1px solid"></canvas>
```

so is there a way to do it with .arc? and if not, any other way to do it? (like border-radius:50%).

Comment: What are the arguments for the arc function? :)

Comment: @Djave sorry for the late reply, do you mean x, y, radius, start angle, end angle?

Comment: That's right the 3rd argument is the radius. If you are able to animate that value, you will be able to do it. Also, be careful with your naming. You name the canvas `ball` but you scaling function also takes an argument of `ball`, you are going to get confused quite quickly like that.

Answer (score 1):

Really, `ball` should contain all the data for... a ball. Instead you set it equal to the canvas:

```
var ball = document.getElementById("MyCanvas");
```

...and use ball1 for the context

```
ball1 = ball.getContext("2d");
```

Firstly, you should rename those variables to something else.

```
var canvas, context;
var ball;
function start(){
  canvas = document.getElementById("MyCanvas");
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
}
window.addEventListener("load",start,false);
```

and then you need to think about an animation loop and all sorts of other things...

Perhaps instead you should think about something much simpler like using pure CSS.

```css
.circle{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 1s;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circle:hover{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: thank you, but I'm trying to make the ball resize without hovering, let's say clicking a button start that takes you to a function next() where the resize code is written, I tried doing it but it grows with 0s duration even tho I did write `transition: transform 10s`.